# Will the Ubuntu packaging and uploading process change in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome, package-management, software-center

I am in the process of creating a program for Ubuntu, and intend to upload it to the Ubuntu Software Center.

Will the packaging and uploading process change in Ubuntu 16.04 due to the switch to the Gnome Software Center?

If I upload my package and it doesn't get processed and released till after the Ubuntu 16.04 release, could I still expect my program to be included in the new software center?

Comment: "And so, right now, **it looks like** we will be replacing [the USC] with GNOME Software Centre”, explains Ubuntu desktop manager Will Cooke at the Ubuntu Online Summit."  You take that as a given? ;-) Besides that: packaging is likely to change to "snappy" format or change to it with 16.10. But... it will be guesswork since 16.04 has not arrived yet ;) But you can also expect backwards compatibility I would assume or some transitioning process/

Comment: @Rinzwind true, I saw it on http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/11/the-ubuntu-software-centre-is-being-replace-in-16-04-lts - I'll have to blame the press then =)